# Rails, RSpec upgrade 2.10 -> 2.14: how do I port my custom spec methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rspec2, rspec-rails

I recently upgraded a Ruby on Rails project from rspec-core / rspec-rails 2.10.1 to 2.14. Now (as I feared) a lot of tests are failing, but just because some methods have been changed. I have already fixed deprecations (stub! -> stub, mock -> double) but there are some more. One important method I use everywhere is something I picked up here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/126993 to stub association methods:

```
module RSpec
  module Mocks
    module Mock
      def stub_association!(association_name, methods_to_be_stubbed = {})
        mock_association = RSpec::Mocks::Mock.new(association_name.to_s)
        methods_to_be_stubbed.each do |method, return_value|
          mock_association.stub(method).and_return(return_value)
        end
        self.stub(association_name).and_return(mock_association)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now this throws the following error message:

```
 Failure/Error: @foo.stub_association!(:children, :sorted => [])
   Double "Foo_1910" received unexpected message :stub_association! with (:children, {:sorted=>[]})
```

I expect the module names above have changed, but I couldn't figure out how exactly. Any hints would be appreciated.

Secondly, I used code like this to stub controller methods:

```
112) ApplicationHelper admin_link_to not logged in: should output nothing
  Failure/Error: stub(:authenticate_with_http_basic).and_return nil
    Stub :authenticate_with_http_basic received unexpected message :and_return with (nil)
```

where the controller method is this

```
def admin_link_to(...)
  return link_to(...) if logged_in? and current_user.has_role?(:admin)
end
```

and `logged_in?` calls `authenticate_with_http_basic do |login, password| ...`. 
Similarly I used to stub `request` to serve fake request objects to the controller or helper being tested.

How can I do this in rspec-rails 2.14?

## Update

It seems that apart from renaming `Mock` to `TestDouble` (neede for the `stub_association!`call above) I just needed to put `controller` or `helper` in front of my `stub(...)` calls, depending on what is being tested. So

```
stub(:authenticate_with_http_basic).and_return nil
```

becomes

```
helper.stub(:authenticate_with_http_basic).and_return nil
```

For most cases, this works fine. Renaming `Mock` to `TestDouble` was only half the cake though - I still cannot use my `stub_association!` method on real objects, only on mocks (or doubles, as they are now called).

So I'm 80% there. Anybody up for the last 20%? :)